# genealogytree add uncle's wife and cousins

Tags: genealogytree

I would like to add a wife for the uncle in the family tree shown below and to add their children (self's cousin). While this seems to be an extremely simple task, I have struggled unsuccessfully to do it.

[image]

The code for my MWE is as follows:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \genealogytree[template=signpost,
    highlight/.style={pivot,box={colback=yellow!20,no shadow,fuzzy halo}}
  ]{
    parent{
        g[female]{sister}
        c[highlight,male]{Self}
        c[male]{brother}
        c[female]{sister}
        parent{
            c[male]{uncle}
            g[highlight,male]{father}
            parent
              {
                g[highlight,male]{grandfather}
                p[highlight,male]{great grandfather}
                p[female]{great grandmother}
              }
            parent{
                g[female]{grandmother}
              }
          }
        parent
          {
            g[female]{mother}
          }
      }
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You have made your tree as an ancestor graph (with `parent` nodes), but with the listed persons and the ones you want to add you should make it as a descendant graph with `child` nodes instead. See section 4.3 in the genealogytree documentation! (It's also possible you want a Sandclock tree – section 4.5.)

If the actual full tree really is an ancestor graph and you want to still put in something extra in it you need to combine trees. See section 2.4!

Comment: @David pls have a look if the answer suits your requirement

Comment: @David pls have a look if the answer suits your requirement

Comment: @David pls have a look if the answer suits your requirement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should suit your requirement

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \genealogytree[template=signpost,
    highlight/.style={pivot,box={colback=yellow!20,no shadow,fuzzy halo}}
  ]{
        child{ g{ggf} p{ggm}
                child{ g{gf} p{gm}
                        child{ g{father}p{mother}
                                c{sister}c{self}c{brother}c{sister}}
                        child{ g{uncle}p{uncle wife}
                                c{child1}c{child2}c{child3}}}}}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**EDIT**

Maybe the OP wanted the color version -- since there is nothing to do else in the lock-down here is color version

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \genealogytree[template=signpost,
    highlight/.style={pivot,box={colback=yellow!20,no shadow,fuzzy halo}}
    ]{
        child{ g[male, highlight]{great gramps} p[female]{great grandma}
            child{ g[male, highlight]{gramps} p[female]{grandma}
                child{ g[male, highlight]{father}p[female]{mother}
                    c[female]{sister}c[male, highlight]{self}c[male]{brother}c[female]{sister}}
                child{ g[male]{uncle}p[female]{uncle wife}
                    c[male]{cousin1}c[male]{cousin2}c[female]{cousin3}}}}}
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: @David pls have a look if the answer suits your requirement

Comment: js bibra:  This is incredibly helpful. Sorry about the delay in getting back to you. Thanks again!

Comment: request to accept the answer if it suits